# How to visualize values ​in array list as fft in Python

Tags: python, visualization, fft

I have array values ​​that I pulled from the dataset
and I want to make visualizations by applying fft to them

MyCode is:

```py
data = df["Value"]
data
smpl = []
for i in data:
  i = i.split(",")
  smpl.append(i)
smpl
```

and `smpl` array like

`[['2375.000', '2437.000', '2375.000', '2250.000', '2312.000', '2312.000', '2375.000', '2375.000', '2375.000', '2375.000', '2312.000', '2375.000', '2375.000', '2375.000', '2437.000', '2437.000', '2312.000', '2312.000', '2312.000', '2437.000', '2375.000', '2375.000', '2437.000', '2437.000', '2437.000', '2312.000', '2375.000', '2250.000', '2250.000', ....`

How can i do it ?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: You will have to convert the strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly refer to the Scipy fft() manual. It has the instructions for exactly what you're trying to do. Here's the link to the manual:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/fft.html